# Laravel + JWT Authentication token_not_provided

Tags: angularjs, laravel, jwt

I'm developing app using AngularJS for a frontend and laravel + JWTokens Authentication as a backend. I have an issue with authentication process on the real host. On local host everything is quiet ok, but when I try to login on the real host it always returns error 400 token_not_provided.

I've tried to change .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Still get same error. Then i checked the headers. Localhost get headers have Authentication header + Bearer with token, but on real host there is no such header. I spend three days already, checked alot of topics but didnt find a solution. Sorry for my english

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Apache/2.4.12
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Img1a1ZkWFwvbmdlMHR4M21cL2dGbnpCZz09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJSQkowODBNdXRQMHgxU0pOQURFbVNHR3FXXC9FWGhPSkttYmRkbVljaGJjTmV0bmdqTWZTM0F2aFZDdnlxY0hxekNLbmI2ZHlJYndMVWdwZTlmRjVcLzR3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiIwZjI3ODI4NTllOWFhMzJiYzc3MTY4MWRkOTA3NzgxODU5MTk2MmQ4YWIzZjYyNmUwMjg2Mjk0NDUzZmI4ZWRkIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 19-Oct-2015 20:12:23 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-encoding: chunked
x-powered-by: PHP/5.5.27
```

Comment: Can you provide the http response headers and body please

Comment: @TimCodes updated post

Comment: Localhost include Vary: Authorization whether real host doesnt

Comment: Looks like the real server is using session cookies, instead of sending back an JWT token, are you using sessions in local version as well ?

Comment: After the user logs in and the server authenticates the  is it sending back  a JWT as the response in body of the http response?

Comment: @TimCodes yes normally sends a token, but on hosting im not sure